# How to make or run the vim plugins in python2?

Tags: python, vim

I have VIM installed on my Ubuntu pc, I want to run the vim script using python.
So tested it, by `:echo has("python")` it resulted 0 means no, but when I tried `:echo has("python3")`, it resulted 1, thus I can use python3 for vim, but how do I run the programs in python2.

I tested the programs in python3, they run, but I want the programs of python2 to run, as I am more proficient in python2 than python3, though there is no major difference in python2 and python3

Comment: You install a version of Vim compiled with support for Python 2.

Comment: how do i do it, i installed vim by sudo apt-get install vim

Comment: can you tell how do i do this

Comment: try installing any of the following: `vim-nox-py2`, `vim-gnome-py2`
http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=-py2&searchon=names

Comment: try running ``:version`` and check if your vim is built with python2, it should show ``+python`` as one of the options.  If not, rebuild your vim with python2 support.